# Everytime I Try To Quicksave My Fallout 4 Gamesave Corrupts

Tags: fallout-4

So basically yesterday I was exploring the wasteland and decided to quick save so when I went on earlier today I found out the save was corrupt. So I went to test if it was the quick save and I quick saved again then quit and went to see if it was still there and it was corrupt as well as my other save how can I prevent this happening?

Comment: Another fine product by bugthesda.

Comment: I had a similar problem (corruption) with Fallout New Vegas when that first came out. I tracked it back to Steam's "cloud saves" feature. Another common save problem (infinite loading) can sometimes be corrected by loading an autosave or manual save from earlier, and *then* loading the quicksave

Comment: Every time I stop playing I get a corrupt save after all the other saves. The saves I made manually are still there just fine. Are you actually losing saves, or just getting additional corrupt saves?

Comment: Losing saves :(

Answer (score 0):

After performing a save, you must re-enter the pause menu and use the 'Exit' option. This will prevent saves from becoming corrupt.